# I can't upload a file to Vercel deployment

Tags: python, deployment, fastapi, vercel

I need to save a few files to a directory ("ROOTDIR/sabiduria_tool_api/data/"). Then I need to process them. I am doing this process with FastAPI. On my local everything works well but when I deployed to Vercel. I am having the below error

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/task/sabiduria_tool_api/data/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/vc__handler__python.py", line 305, in vc_handler
    response = asgi_cycle(__vc_module.app, body)
  File "/var/task/vc__handler__python.py", line 208, in __call__
    loop.run_until_complete(asgi_task)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/var/task/fastapi/applications.py", line 289, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/var/task/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 273, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 190, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/var/task/sabiduria_tool_api/api/routes/router_sabiduria_tool.py", line 18, in upload_files
    await processer.calculate()
  File "/var/task/sabiduria_tool_api/services/service_sabiduria_tool.py", line 97, in calculate
    await self.save_files()
  File "/var/task/sabiduria_tool_api/services/service_sabiduria_tool.py", line 35, in save_files
    mkdir(self.data_store_path)
```

I have two endpoints, the first one(health check) works well but the second one(POST) is failing.
Here is where the code throws the error

```py
async def save_files(self) -> None:
    if isdir(self.data_store_path):
        old_files = self.get_files()
        for o_file in old_files:
            remove(f"{self.data_store_path}{o_file}")
    else:
        mkdir(self.data_store_path)
    for file in self.files:
        with open(f"{self.data_store_path}{file.filename}", "wb") as destination:
            copyfileobj(file.file, destination)
```

How can I handle that problem?

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system`. You're not allowed to make a directory there. Pick a writable location or start working on Plan B.

Comment: @Woodford I was checking the documentation but I couldn't find info about that. Where can I get the writable directory?

Comment: I don't know anything about Vercel but if it seems that you should be storing this data in a database or cloud storage (e.g. S3) rather than downloading to the local filesystem of the deployed server.

Comment: @Woodford I do not need any cloud storage at all. I am processing the files and then deleting them. Therefore, I just need them for a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: Then just don't write them to disk and process them completely in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vercel allow to write and read files on only `/tmp` folder. I found the solution in [here](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/314#discussioncomment-3609594).

Comment: Please mark your answer as the solution!