# MERN stack project, 'multer' uploaded images can't be shown

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, multer, vercel

I'm a beginner developer, and I'm learning MERN stack developing. I have just Learnt about the Multer Library of express JS and I implemented that. Everything is working fine, but after that, when I'm uploading my server site to vercel, I can't show the images which I have uploaded by multer in my local host.

Here is the server side code:

This is the top of my server side:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
```

This is the code line regarding the path:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

This is the middleware I have written for multer:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});
```

This is the post request i have created to save that picture's name to my mongoDB:

```
 //! Upload via Multer
    app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
      const data = { imageName: req.file.filename };
      const result = await uploadsCollection.insertOne(data);
      res.send(result);
    });
```

After that in my font end I have written code to upload a picture and also for showing the picture by getting the names of the pictures from the DB

FontEnd:

This is the code I wrote to take the photo input:

```
//! For Multer
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState();
  const [galleryReloader, setGalleryReloader] = useState(true);
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const handleInput = async (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    const base64 = await convertBase64(event.target.files[0]);
    setPreview(base64);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    axiosInstance
      .post("/upload", data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data.acknowledged) {
          toast.success("Image Added", {
            position: "top-center",
            autoClose: 2000,
          });
          e.target.reset();
          setGalleryReloader(!galleryReloader);
          setPreview(null);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
```

[
HTML regarding upload:

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex items-center gap-5 w-1/2">
        <input required type="file" onChange={handleInput} />
        <img className="w-22 h-32 rounded-lg" src={preview} alt="" />

        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Add"
          className="bg-title text-white text-sm px-4 py-2 rounded-lg active:scale-90 duration-300 cursor-pointer select-none"
        />
      </form>
```

I converted into base64 for just the preview of that selected picture

Now, I tried to show all the pictures which i have uploaded by multer and stored the names to the DB

Getting the picture names from DB:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance
      .get("/get-uploads")
      .then((res) => {
        setImages(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [galleryReloader]);
```

This is how i tried to show the uploaded pictures:

```
images.map((image) => (
            <img
              key={image._id}
              className="rounded-md w-32 h-32 border border-theme p-2"
              src={`${import.meta.env.VITE_serverUrl}/images/${
                image.imageName
              }`}
              alt=""
            />
          ))
```

This is that .env line to Centralize the server link:

```
  VITE_serverUrl=http://localhost:1000
  # VITE_serverUrl=https://car-doctor-server-amber-ten.vercel.app
```

[That's how I created a public folder and under that a created a folder named 'images'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn5Zg.png)

Everything is working perfectly in my localhost like, uploading an image, previewing and storing into DB, everything is working fine. But when I'm uploading this server-side to varcel, after that These functionalities are not working. That means I can't show the images and I cant upload image.

I'm also sharing my vercel.json file

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the localhost, when I'm selecting image, I am able to see the preview of that. after that. I am clicking the 'add' button. Its also sending the file name to the database and storing that image in my located folder. But after uploading on varcel, these functionalities are not working.

Also I included the pictures regarding differences between localhost output and vercel uotput:

[Localhost Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Dyg.png)
[Vercel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FHpS.png)

What should I do
Please help me

Comment: First debug the point of issue, are you able to upload? check the api call status for upload api in network tab? check DB if data is stored in correct format? check the get api if you are getting the data correctly?

Comment: Sir, but why its working on localhost? Its difficult to find out the issue wheatear its ok on localhost but not ok on vercel? why this difference ?

Comment: There could be many reasons, thats why we have to debug to narrow it down. Some wrong configuration, cors error or any unknown reason.

Comment: maybe: [I can't upload a file to Vercel deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76907775/i-cant-upload-a-file-to-vercel-deployment)